# Text Overflow Ellipsis not working

Tags: html, css, overflow

I know display type table-cell does not work with text - overflow ellipsis . But this is what my problem is like .

I have a file input control that looks like

```
<div class="ui-select form-input" style="display:inline-block; margin-right:5px; margin-bottom:-8px;width:400px;">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <label class="btn btn-info btn-file" for="multiple_input_group">
            <div class="input required">
                <input id="multiple_input_group" type="file" multiple name="files" ng-files="getTheFiles($files)">
            </div> Browse
        </label>
    </span>
    <span class="file-input-label" ng-model="fileName"></span>
</div>
```

Now when you select a file that file name should be displayed on the span text.

The CSS looks like :

```
.file-input-label {
    padding: 0px 10px;
    display: table-cell;
    white-space:nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

When we select a big file name the span gets expanded . It does not come with dotted line...

[image]

I tried to convert the display to block but it messes the UI

```
.file-input-label {
    padding: 0px 10px;
    display: block;
    width:400px;
    height:20px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

[image]

[image]

They are not inline now .. the browse button and the span element are not inline.

Even display:inline-block did not help much

```
.file-input-label {
    padding: 0px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space:nowrap;
    width:400px;
    height:30px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

I thought to set the display of span

```
<span class="input-group-btn" style="display:inline-block;">
```

but even this produces

[image]

What needs to be corrected ?

Comment: Did you tried the `max-width: 0` trick? It should be placed in the `table-cell` rule.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude ... wowww ... sir :) You are a genius.

Comment: So let me add an answer, you accept other answer that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @StrugglingCoder- answer added :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change the `display: table-cell` you have available the `max-width: 0` trick to a cell. It allows to specify the table something that it can be applied the `text-overflow`. So your changes should be:

```
.file-input-label {
    padding: 0px 10px;
    display: table-cell;
    white-space:nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    max-width: 0; /** the only needed change **/
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Text-overflow ellipsis won't work in table-cell display, so you may use inline-block:

```
.file-input-label {
    padding: 0px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space:nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

---

To make ellipsis in table-cell display, you should use sorts of css rules, for eg. width, table-layout...

Refer this google results:
[text overflow on table-cell display](https://www.google.com/search?q=text+overflow+ellipsis+on+table-cell+display&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab).

Comment: you have not defined the class file-input-label in the span.